# Dynamically created tables or one table with relations

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

i dont know what is better. I have something like:

```
Table1:
Name
ID
Structure
```

and Structure is table type data like:

```
Structure:
ID
Name
```

So one element of table 1 can have mulutiple elements of Structure.

what is better:
1)Create subtables with Table1.name as name
2)Make one Structure table with:

```
table1_reference
ID
Name
```

Everything will be used by C++/C# code. I just dont know what is better.

Comment: Are Tables depend of Structures ?

Comment: @Taumantis Did you manage to accomplish what you wanted?

Comment: @up yes i did. Best way was testing perfomance:) and i did like u said, but... for very large amount of data dynamic tables would be better, but we are talking about max sharepoint content data base size . answere checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like you should remove the structure column from `table1` and create a cross reference table with foreign keys from `table1` (ID) and `structure` (ID) and you insert there the occurrences of the relationship of both tables.

When you want to have information from them, you simply join them by the IDs.

Don't simply add a column for table1_reference in table structures, because you would have the column name with a lot of duplicate information.

It should be:

```
Table1:
ID
Name

Structure:
ID
Name

table1_structure:
ID
TABLE1_ID
STRUCTURE_ID
```